# Should I be exposing Stream<T> on my interface?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

If I am writing .NET code I would often expose `IEnumerable<T>` where-ever it could possibly make sense. Maybe it was down to LINQ and the fact you could use foreach, but it felt "right" to do it.

```
private List<String> _myList;

public IEnumerable<String> MyList
{
    get { return _myList; }
}
```

Now I am writing Java 8 code and I am debating whether I should be exposing `Stream<T>` where possible in the same way? Maybe its because I have to call `Collection.stream()` and it feels like it is "doing work", but it doesn't feel right?

```
private Collection<String> myCollection;

public Stream<String> getStuff() {
    return myCollection.stream();
}
```

Is `Stream<T>` meant to be exposed on an interface in the same way that `IEnumerable<T>` might be?

Comment: If you return a collection, the caller can stream it... or not. If you return a stream, it does create extra work (as in CPU time) to turn it into a collection. So unless it makes no sense to do anything else than "iterating" over the returned collection once and be done with it, in which case a stream would be just fine, I would return a collection as it gives more flexibility.

Comment: @assylias - I guess the reason I was asking is that I disagree with the fact that you have to call `.stream()` in order to get access to the functional query operators, I think the Stream interface should have been added to Collection, but I guess that isn't the Java way...

Comment: Brian Goetz has already posted a pretty thorough answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24679745/1441122

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question. After all, it isn’t hard to support both, e.g.

```
Collection<Foo> getStuff();
default Stream<Foo> stuff() {
    return getStuff().stream();
}
```

so code using your interface doesn’t need an explicit `stream()` call, while implementors of the `interface` don’t need to bother with it as well.

As you are always exposing a `Stream` support whether via `Collection.stream()` or explicitly, the question is whether you want to *expose the `Collection`*. While it is cheap to provide a `Stream` for a `Collection` back-end it might turn out to be expensive to collect a `Collection` from a `Stream`.

So an interface exposing both ways suggests that they are equally usable while for an implementation not using a `Collection` back-end one of these methods might be way more expensive than the other.

So if you are sure that all implementations, including future ones, will always use (or have to support) a `Collection` it might be useful to expose it though the API as `Collection`s support certain operations which `Stream` doesn’t. That’s especially true if you support modification of the underlying data via the exposed `Collection`.

Otherwise, supporting `Stream` access only might be the better choice. This gives implementations the freedom to have other back-ends than a `Collection`. However, that also implies that this API does not support Java versions prior to Java 8.

Comment: I think the thing that has made it "click" for me is the modification point. I will expose `Stream<T>` - thank you! (I don't support pre-Java 8). (I do understand your point about collecting from a stream)

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you want to be a `Stream` yourself, primarily depends on whether you're truly a `Stream` with the corresponding powers, i.e. support parallelization (not all `Stream`s do, but it's one of the many benefits of `Stream`s, and it's an important one). Normally I'd rather be a `Collection` and let myself be `Stream`ed by the corresponding API calls.

The `getStuff()` method, returning `Stream<String>` from `myCollection.stream()` looks right to me.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid Stream where possible in interfaces.

Streams may
* be finite or infinite
* be sequential or parallel
* be ordered or non-ordered
* need closing or not

Neither the implementors of an interface nor the clients of the interface can know which of these characteristics should (not) apply or which they need to guard against.

Choosing the most flexible return type in an interface just means that clients have the full burden of guarding against all possibilities. It is generally much more useful in an interface to restrict the returned datatype so that implementors know what assumptions they can rely one (for the same reason returning `Collection` itself is not very useful in most cases, it is more useful to return `List, Set, Iterable, InputStream` to indicate rights and duties of clients when consuming the data).

And when you need to change the characteristics of the returned data, change the interface,b break your clients intentionally, so that they can update their algorithms to the changed situation.

That's much more useful than to say: "My method returns a Stream, so now I can return an infinite stream instead of a finite one, and the client code still compiles, how wonderful!". It is not wonderful, it is a horrible source of bugs to do that. Client code should **NOT** continue to compile with such drastic changes, so using datatypes that are explicit about finity, parallelity, orderedness and duty to `close()` is a much better choice.

Think like this: If remaining flexible was so great, then all interfaces that in Java7 return `List` or `Set` or `Queue` would be returning `Iterable` instead, to remain flexible in what datatype to actually return. But this is not what most interfaces do returning a Collection instead tells clients they can safely rely on a size() method, and returning a Set means they can safely rely on non-duplication, as an example. Being specific and restrictive in interfaces is not a sin, it is a virtue.