# Can a Java 8 `Stream` be parallel without you even asking for it?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

As I see it, the obvious code, when using Java 8 `Stream`s, whether they be "object" streams or primitive streams (that is, `IntStream` and friends) would be to just use:

```
someStreamableResource.stream().whatever()
```

But then, quite a few "streamable resources" also have `.parallelStream()`.

What isn't clear when reading the javadoc is whether `.stream()` streams are always sequential, and whether `.parallelStream()` streams are always parallel...

And then there is `Spliterator`, and in particular its [`.characteristics()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#characteristics--), one of them being that it can be [`CONCURRENT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#CONCURRENT), or even [`IMMUTABLE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#IMMUTABLE).

My gut feeling is that in fact, whether a `Stream` can be, or not, parallel by default, or parallel at all, is guided by its underlying `Spliterator`...

Am I on the right track? I have read, and read again, the javadocs, and still cannot come up with a clear answer to this question...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, through the lens of *specification*.  Whether a stream is parallel or sequential is part of a stream's state.  Stream-creation methods should specify whether they create a sequential or parallel stream (and most in the JDK do), but they are not required to say so.  If your stream source doesn't say, don't assume.  If someone passes you a stream, don't assume.

Parallel streams are allowed to fall back to sequential at their discretion (since a sequential implementation *is* a parallel implementation, just a potentially imperfect one); the opposite is not true.

Now, through the lens of *implementation*.  In the stream-creation methods in Collections and other JDK classes, we stick to a discipline of "create a sequential stream unless the user explicitly asks for parallelism".  (Other libraries, however, make different choices.  If they're polite, they'll specify their behavior.)

The relationship between stream parallelism and Spliterator only goes in one direction.  A Spliterator can refuse to split -- effectively denying any parallelism -- but it can't *demand* that a client split it.  So an uncooperative Spliterator can undermine parallelism, but not determine it.

Comment: "A Spliterator can refuse to split -- effectively denying any parallelism" - the Spliterator documentation is not very clear on that point: "Operations using a Spliterator that cannot split... are **unlikely** to benefit from parallelism." Is there a Stream implementation that can parallelize itself without `trySplit`? Is there a more definitive way to force a stream to remain sequential?

Comment: @shmosel Calling `.sequential()` requires the stream to go sequential.  But parallelism can only be requested, not required, as there are many factors that all need to come together to achieve actual parallelism.

Comment: I'm asking as the stream creator. Is there a way to create a Spliterator or a Stream that cannot be parallelized? I would think that could be accomplished by not implementing `trySplit`, but the documentation is not clear on that point.

Comment: @shmosel Usually the "stream creator" (I assume you mean client?) is not the implementor of the spliterator.  If you want a sequential stream, call .sequential() on the stream.

Comment: No, I mean the implementor.

Comment: @shmosel in that case, just make `.trySplit()` return `null`

Comment: @fge The documentation isn't clear on whether that's enough to prevent parallelization. See my initial comment.

Answer (score 2):

The [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) doesn't have much to say on the matter:

> Streams are created with an initial choice of sequential or parallel
>   execution. (For example, Collection.stream() creates a sequential
>   stream, and Collection.parallelStream() creates a parallel one.)

Regarding your line of reasoning that some intermediate operations may not be thread safe, you may want to read the [package summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps). The package summary discusses intermediate operations, stateful vs stateless, and how to properly use a `Stream` in some depth.

> Side-effects in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in
>   general, discouraged, as they can often lead to unwitting violations
>   of the statelessness requirement, as well as other thread-safety
>   hazards.

Behavioral parameters being the arguments given to stateless intermediate operations.

> the API cannot make any assumptions

The API can make any assumption it wishes. The onus is on the user of the API to meet those assumptions. However, assumptions may limit usability. The `Stream` API *discourages* the creation of a stateless intermediate operation that is not thread-safe. Since it is discouraged instead of prohibited, most `Stream`s will be sequential "by default".

Comment: Thank you for giving me a new light on what I have already read but obviously was too obtuse to spot...

Answer (score 1):

Well, answer to self...

After thinking about it a little more seriously (go figure, such things only happen after I actually ask the question), I actually came up with a reason why...

Intermediate operations may **NOT** be thread safe; as such, the API cannot make any assumptions, hence if the user wants a parallel stream, it has to explicitly ask for it and ensure that all intermediate operations used in the stream are thread safe.

There is however the somewhat misleading case of `Collector`s; since a `Collector` cannot know by advance whether it will be called as a terminal operation on a stream which is parallel or not, the contract makes it clear that "just to be safe", any `Collector` must be thread safe.

Comment: Actually, [the documentation of `Collector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) doesn’t mandate that a `Collector` must be thread safe. It’s the responsibility of the `Stream` implementation to use the `Collector` correctly to ensure thread safety. On the other hand, it’s required that “the collector functions must satisfy an identity and an associativity constraints” which is required to make the overall operation thread-safe…

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html): "When you create a stream, it is always a serial stream unless otherwise specified." 
And [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream--): "It is allowable for this method (`parallelStream`) to return a sequential stream."

`CONCURRENT` and `IMMUTABLE` aren't (directly) related to this. They specify whether the underlying collection can be modified without rendering the spliterator invalid or whether it is immutable respectively.  The feature of spliterator that *does* pretty much define the behavior of parallelStream is `trySplit`. Terminal operations on a parallel stream will eventually invoke `trySplit`, and whatever that implementation does will in the end of the day define what parts, if any, of the data are processed in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

This appart is not specification constrained right now, however the short answer is **NO**.
There exist `parallelStream()` and `stream()` functions but that just provides you ways to access to a parallel or sequential implementations of common basic operations to process the stream.
Currently runtime can't assume that your operations are thread safe without explicit usage of `parallelStream()` or `parallel()` call, then default implementation of `stream()` is to have a sequential behavior.