# Can a Collector's combiner function ever be used on sequential streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Sample program:

```
public final class CollectorTest
{
    private CollectorTest()
    {
    }

    private static <T> BinaryOperator<T> nope()
    {
        return (t, u) -> { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("nope"); };
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        final Collector<Integer, ?, List<Integer>> c
            = Collector.of(ArrayList::new, List::add, nope());

        IntStream.range(0, 10_000_000).boxed().collect(c);
    }
}
```

So, to simplify matters here, there is no final transformation, so the resulting code is quite simple.

Now, `IntStream.range()` produces a sequential stream. I simply box the results into `Integer`s and then my contrived `Collector` collects them into a `List<Integer>`. Pretty simple.

And no matter how many times I run this sample program, the `UnsupportedOperationException` never hits, which means my dummy combiner is never called.

I kind of expected this, but then I have already misunderstood streams enough that I have to ask the question...

Can a `Collector`'s combiner ever be called when the stream is *guaranteed* to be sequential?

Comment: I bet there will be no guarantees about this, even though there's no need for it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that or I have (again) misread the javadoc and it is actually explicit about it, one way or the other...

Comment: "*The combiner however always throws*" > I didn't understand this part of your sentence - always throws what?

Comment: The most relevant part of the docs would appear to be "*A sequential implementation of a reduction using a collector would create a single result container using the supplier function, and invoke the accumulator function once for each input element. A parallel implementation would partition the input, create a result container for each partition, accumulate the contents of each partition into a subresult for that partition, and then use the combiner function to merge the subresults into a combined result.*", which is pretty loose wording.

Comment: @Duncan I think he means that if the combiner (i.e the `nope` BinaryOperator) is used when the elements are collected, it'll always throw an exception.

Comment: @Duncan what AlexisC said; and the part of the documentation you quote is what I have read as well, however as you say it is pretty loose as you mention

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24316429/2711488), Stuart Marks describes the role of the *combiner* in the `reduce` case and he doesn’t mention any possibility for a sequential combine op.

Comment: May be relevant: You should never make any assumptions about the stream anyhow ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/27950586/3182664 )

Comment: what about formalizing a `Collector<T,A,R>` that doesn't have a `Characteristic.UNORDERED` property. see `.of` in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A careful reading of the streams implementation code in [ReduceOps.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b132/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/ReduceOps.java) reveals that the combine function is called only when a `ReduceTask` completes, and `ReduceTask` instances are used only when evaluating a pipeline in parallel. Thus, ***in the current implementation,*** the combiner is never called when evaluating a sequential pipeline.

There is nothing in the specification that guarantees this, however. A `Collector` is an interface that makes requirements on its implementations, and there are no exemptions granted for sequential streams. Personally, I find it difficult to imagine why sequential pipeline evaluation might need to call the combiner, but someone with more imagination than me might find a clever use for it, and implement it. The specification allows for it, and even though today's implementation doesn't do it, you still have to think about it.

This should not surprising. The design center of the streams API is to support parallel execution on an equal footing with sequential execution. Of course, it is possible for a program to observe whether it is being executed sequentially or in parallel. But the design of the API is to support a style of programming that allows either.

If you're writing a collector and you find that it's impossible (or inconvenient, or difficult) to write an associative combiner function, leading you to want to restrict your stream to sequential execution, maybe this means you're heading in the wrong direction. It's time to step back a bit and think about approaching the problem a different way.

A common reduction-style operation that doesn't require an associative combiner function is called *fold-left*. The main characteristic is that the fold function is applied strictly left-to-right, proceeding one at a time. I'm not aware of a way to parallelize fold-left.

When people try to contort collectors the way we've been talking about, they're usually looking for something like fold-left. The Streams API doesn't have direct API support for this operation, but it's pretty easy to write. For example, suppose you want to reduce a list of strings using this operation: repeat the first string and then append the second. It's pretty easy to demonstrate that this operation isn't associative:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

System.out.println(list.stream()
    .collect(StringBuilder::new,
             (a, b) -> a.append(a.toString()).append(b),
             (a, b) -> a.append(a.toString()).append(b))); // BROKEN -- NOT ASSOCIATIVE
```

Run sequentially, this produces the desired output:

```
aabaabcaabaabcdaabaabcaabaabcde
```

But when run in parallel, it might produce something like this:

```
aabaabccdde
```

Since it "works" sequentially, we could enforce this by calling `sequential()` and back this up by having the combiner throw an exception. In addition, the supplier must be called exactly once. There's no way to combine the intermediate results, so if the supplier is called twice, we're already in trouble. But since we "know" the supplier is called only once in sequential mode, most people don't worry about this. In fact, I've seen people write "suppliers" that return some existing object instead of creating a new one, in violation of the supplier contract.

In this use of the 3-arg form of `collect()`, we have two out of the three functions breaking their contracts. Shouldn't this be telling us to do things a different way?

The main work here is being done by the accumulator function. To accomplish a fold-style reduction, we can apply this function in a strict left-to-right order using `forEachOrdered()`. We have to do a bit of setup and finishing code before and after, but that's no problem:

```
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
list.parallelStream()
    .forEachOrdered(b -> a.append(a.toString()).append(b));
System.out.println(a.toString());
```

Naturally, this works fine in parallel, though the performance benefits of running in parallel may be somewhat negated by the ordering requirements of `forEachOrdered()`.

In summary, if you find yourself wanting to do a mutable reduction but you're lacking an associative combiner function, leading you to restrict your stream to sequential execution, recast the problem as a *fold-left* operation and use `forEachRemaining()` on your accumulator function.

Comment: I am fully aware of the API, I was just curious ;) Excellent answer, as usual. And I learned some things as well...

Comment: @stuart-marks Did you mean to write "...recast the problem as a fold-left operation and use `forEachOrdered()` on ..." at the very end, in the summary?

Answer (score 3):

As observed in previous comments from @MarkoTopolnik and @Duncan there is no guarantee that `Collector.combiner()` on sequential mode is called to produce a reduced result. In fact, the Java doc is a little bit subjective in this point, which can to lead an not appropriate interpretation.

> (...) A parallel implementation would partition the input, create a result container for each partition, accumulate the contents of each partition into a subresult for that partition, and **then use the combiner function to merge the subresults into a combined result**.

According to [NoBlogDefFound](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/07/introduction-to-writing-custom.html) combinator is used only in parallel mode. See the partial quotation below:

> **combiner()** is used to join two accumulators together into one. It is used when collector is executed in parallel, splitting input Stream and collecting parts independently first.

To show more clear this issue I re-write the first code and I put two approaches (serial and parallel).

---

```
public final class CollectorTest
{
    private CollectorTest()
    {
    }

    private static <T> BinaryOperator<T> nope()
    {
        return (t, u) -> { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("nope"); };
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {

        final Collector<Integer, ?, List<Integer>> c =
                Collector
                    .of(ArrayList::new, List::add, nope());

        // approach sequential
        Stream<Integer> sequential = IntStream
                .range(0, 10_000_000)
                .boxed();

        System.out.println("isParallel:" + sequential.isParallel());
        sequential
                .collect(c);

        // approach parallel
        Stream<Integer> parallel = IntStream
                .range(0, 10_000_000)
                .parallel()
                .boxed();

        System.out.println("isParallel:" + parallel.isParallel());
        parallel
                .collect(c);
    }
}
```

After running this code we can get the output:

```
isParallel:false
isParallel:true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nope
    at com.stackoverflow.lambda.CollectorTest.lambda$nope$0(CollectorTest.java:18)
    at com.stackoverflow.lambda.CollectorTest$$Lambda$3/2001049719.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.combine(ReduceOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.combine(ReduceOps.java:160)
```

So, according this result we can infer that `Collector's combiner` can be called only by the parallel execution.

Comment: However that is but one example of a `Stream`, and what is more it is provided by the JDK...

Comment: @fge I was thinking that your main question was about only the combiner and stream. Do you have any idea about others points that I should mention ? My intention was to show the same usage that you comment but adding the parallel behavior, in this case rising the exception.