# How can I sort a Map based upon on the size of its Collection values?

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I have a `HashMap` like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("USA", Arrays.asList("CA","IA","IL"));
map.put("India", Arrays.asList("MUM","CAL"));
map.put("Canada", Arrays.asList("TOR"));
```

I want to sort the map depending on the size of the list value, in ascending order. How can I do that?

In this case, I would like the keys to be ordered Canada, India, USA.

Comment: You can't sort a HashMap, because HashMaps don't support ordering. You'll have to put them into a data structure that does support ordering (i.e. List, LinkedHashMap) if you want to sort them.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`HashMap` does not have a guaranteed iteration order so you will need to collect to a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) in order for the sorting to be meaningful.

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

Map<String, List<String>> sorted = map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().size()))
    .collect(toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        (a, b) -> { throw new AssertionError(); },
        LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
```

The `AssertionError` is thrown because a combiner function is [only used on parallel streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210176/can-a-collectors-combiner-function-ever-be-used-on-sequential-streams), which we are not using.

You can also use [`comparingByValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue-java.util.Comparator-) if you find it more readable:

```
import static java.util.Map.Entry.comparingByValue;

Map<String, List<String>> sorted = map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(comparingByValue(comparingInt(List::size)))
    // ... as above
```

Comment: @JGFMK `import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;`

Comment: The first code works a treat. The latter doesn't. Also if you want size descending use ...................................... `(e -> -e.getValue().size())` in the `comparingInt`. You can see latter doesn't here: https://code.sololearn.com/ccz02MbYMYs1/#java [gives 2 compilation errors: 1) cannot find symbol for comparingByValue
2) argument mismatch; invalid method reference]

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't specify `import static java.util.Map.Entry.comparingByValue;`  Good catch, I will fix it

Comment: That still didn't work. Got a bit further. https://code.sololearn.com/cJPV8XUUW9ce/#java error: incompatible types: Stream<Entry<String,List<String>>> cannot be converted to Map<String,List<String>>
          .sorted(comparingByValue(comparingInt(List::size)));
                 ^

Comment: You cannot assign a stream to a map.  If you want to make a map, you must use `collect(toMap(...))` as in the first example.  Somebody edited the original answer and removed the explanation that `comparingbyValue(comparingInt(..))` is only a replacement for `comparingInt(e -> ...)`.  I will try to find time to roll back their edit and fix this.

Comment: I think you can get there from profile > all actions > revisions...

Answer (score 2):

```html
public static <K,V extends Collection> Map<K,V> sortMap(Map<K,V> map){
        return map.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e2.getValue().size(), e1.getValue().size()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.

1. Map doesn't support sorting.
2. SortedMap doesn't support sorting on values only sorting on keys.

As a result of this using a Map or SortedMap isn't going to help you. What you need to do is iterate over you map and put each `Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>` into a collection such as a List and then sort the list with a custom compare. See this example [TreeMap sort by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value) or this example [Sorting LinkedHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184378/sorting-linkedhashmap)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply map the hash to list of Pair() and then sort the list

```
val map: MutableMap<String, List<String>> = HashMap()

map["USA"] = listOf("CA", "IA", "IL")
map["India"] = listOf("MUM", "CAL")
map["Canada"] = listOf("TOR")

val sortedPairs = map.map { Pair(it.key, it.value) }.sortedBy { it.second.size }.toMap()

println("sorted List: $sortedPairs")
```