# java-stream, map, keys not related to object

Tags: java, java-stream

So I have a list of integer that is insIds, from this I can get a list of ABCs, I want to map them to an entry in map (notice that we can not getInsId from Abc.getIns)

This is what I want it to be: (but since we **do not** have getInsId we are not able to write this way)

```
Map<Integer, Integer> insIdToAbcId = abcController
          .findAbcsByInsIds(insIds)
          .stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Abc::getInsId,
            Abc::getAbcId));
```

I am not sure how to write it in order to have the mapping relationship I want.

Known list of integer: `insIds`

Known function that will take insIds and return list:

```
abcController.findAbcsByInsIds(insIds)
```

And then is what I am not sure about: how to map insId to AbcId

(expect output: `Map<Integer, Integer> insIdToAbcId` )

Comment: full code, please

Comment: @TheTechGuy not sure what is missing? I think everything needed is here already? Known list of integer: insIds, known function that will take insIds and return list<Abc>: abcController.findAbcsByInsIds(insIds). And then is what I am not sure about: how to map

Comment: how your expected output should look like?

Comment: @TheTechGuy   expect output: Map<Integer, Integer> insIdToAbcId

Comment: I guess you have that `Abc ` class already

Comment: @TheTechGuy  but can't map them..

Comment: Unless there's an ordered one-to-one relationship between `insIds` and the result of `findAbcsByInsIds()`, I don't think it's possible. Is there a variant of the method that takes a single ID?

Comment: @shmosel yes it's an  ordered one-to-one relationship between insIds and the result of findAbcsByInsIds(). The number of insIds  can be really big so I want to use one sql to find them all.(findAbcsByInsIds will just have one sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's an ordered one-to-one relationship between the items in `insIds` and the result of `findAbcsByInsIds()`, you can join the lists by index:

```
List<Abc> abcs = abcController.findAbcsByInsIds(insIds);
Map<Integer, Integer> insIdToAbcId = IntStream.range(0, insIds.size())
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(insIds::get, i -> abcs.get(i).getAbcId()));
```

Comment: You can't use a collector on a primitive stream.

Answer (score 1):

This is a prime example of a problem where Stream is not the right solution.

After the `findAbcsByInsIds()` call, you have two lists of equal size, and you want to match them, by position, i.e. you need to parallel iterate them.

So do that:

```
List<Integer> insIds = /*...*/
List<Abc> abcList = abcController.findAbcsByInsIds(insIds);

Map<Integer, Integer> insIdToAbcId = new HashMap<>(insIds.size() * 4 / 3 + 1);
Iterator<Integer> insIter = insIds.iterator();
Iterator<Abc> abcIter = abcList.iterator();
while (insIter.hasNext())
    insIdToAbcId.put(insIter.next(), abcIter.next().getAbcId());
```

This code will perform well, even if lists are `LinkedList`.
The `HashMap` was preallocated to appropriate size, so resizing is eliminated, preventing need to rehash, i.e. for better performance.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the rationale behind `list.size() * 4 / 3 + 1`? Doesn't `HashMap` take care of that internally?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner The [`HashMap​(int initialCapacity)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap-int-) constructor *"constructs an empty `HashMap` with the specified initial capacity and the default **load factor (0.75)**"*. Once you've added `initialCapacity * 3/4` elements, the `HashMap` is resized. To prevent resizing / rehashing, we need the `initialCapacity` to be *at least* `size * 4/3`, and since the division operator may round down, simply adding 1 will ensure that `initialCapacity >= size * 4/3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map< Integer, Integer > insIdToAbcId = findAbcsByInsIds( insIds )
            .stream( )
            .collect( HashMap::new, ( map, abc ) -> map.put( insIds.get( map.size( ) ), abc.getAbcId( ) ), ( a, b ) -> {} );
```

For each version to address the contract concerns about the third parameter

```
    Map< Integer, Integer > map = new HashMap<>(  );
    findAbcsByInsIds( insIds )
            .forEach( (abc) -> map.put( insIds.get( map.size( ) ), abc.getAbcId( ) ));
```

This is actually simpler and there in no need for boxing, auxiliary streams of even a collector. But about the collect method one could use an unsupported exception to make sure it is never called, should the implementation details of the underline jre change, it would not change without one's knowledge.

Comment: What's with the combiner?

Comment: it is never called

Comment: So what? It's a required argument.

Comment: that is why it is there

Comment: Well, no. You're violating the [requirement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) that *a partially accumulated result `p`... must be equivalent to `combiner.apply(p, supplier.get())`.*

Comment: but there is no partial result.

Comment: Actually I don't think that requirement is broken. But the one in the next paragraph is.

Comment: I see what you mean, but first, if it was a full collector implementation this could well be an unsupported exception. there is no violation it there is no entry for your violation test.

Comment: That's not how it works. Just because the code works under certain circumstances doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: the exactly what the semantics "for all" means in a set. an empty set is an empty set. But this is nice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210176/can-a-collectors-combiner-function-ever-be-used-on-sequential-streams

Comment: also, there is the exception -> which is actually recommended by Raul-Gabriel Urma, Mario Fusco and Alan Mycroft

Comment: I don't know what "for all" you're referencing. And what part of the book are you referring to?

Comment: The "for all" I was referering to the javadocs for stream. For the book "Note that in reality this collector can’t be used in parallel, because the algorithm is
inherently sequential. This means the combiner method won’t ever be invoked, and you
could leave its implementation empty (or better, throw an UnsupportedOperation-
Exception)."

Comment: Where are both of those references?

Comment: but point being, I would fell pretty safe with an exception there. otherwise a custom collector would simplify this problem too. in any case, if the op is uncomfortable with the combine, I doubt they could not rewrite this with a forEach and an auxiliary variable.

Comment: the book is on pag 154, and the java doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.htm

Comment: Ok, I see the quote in the book, but I disagree with the authors. The specification doesn't differentiate between parallel and sequential streams, as pointed out in the answer you linked (by a JDK developer, I should add), and to assume otherwise is dangerous. I'm still not seeing any "for all" on the Stream page that's relevant to our discussion.

Comment: This means that for all u, combiner(identity, u) is equal to u.

Comment: That's from the `reduce()` method.

Comment: next to (The combiner is necessary in parallel reductions, where the input is partitioned, a partial accumulation computed for each partition, and then the partial results are combined to produce a final result.)

Comment: That's an implementation note, not the specification. Anyway, we're discussing `collect()`, not `reduce()`.

Comment: As I see those note are for both: The streams classes have multiple forms of general reduction operations, called reduce() and collect()