# Drop values to keep only N occurrences

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I was doing today some katas from Codewars. I had to write function which keeps only N of same elements from array, for example:

```
{1,2,3,4,1}, N=1 -> {1,2,3,4}
{2,2,2,2}, N=2 -> {2,2}
```

I come up with that solution using streams:

```
 public static int[] deleteNth(int[] elements, int maxOcurrences) {
    List<Integer> ints = Arrays.stream(elements)
                               .boxed()
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return ints.stream().filter(x -> Collections.frequency(ints, x) <= maxOcurrences)
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .toArray();
}
```

So, firstly change ints to Integers, then filter if freq is higher than N.
 But this isn't working, because repeating elements have identical frequency regardless of theirs positions. It looks like values are filtered after filter call. How can I fix this to get correct values?

PS: I know thats O(n^2), but this isn't a problem for me.

Comment: Yeah, occurrences beyond limit should be discarded and order should be kept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a great case to not use streams. Stream are not always the best approach when stateful operations are involved.

But it can be definitely done, and also the question asks specifically for streams, so you can use the followings.

---

**Using forEachOrdered**

You can use `forEachOrdered` with should ensure the order (here obvioulsy the stream has to be **sequential**):

```
public static int[] deleteNth(int[] elements, int maxOcurrs) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.stream(elements).forEachOrdered(elem -> {
        if (Collections.frequency(list, elem) < maxOcurrs) list.add(elem);
    });
    return list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
}
```

---

**Using collect**

Given some circunstanses you can use the `collect` method to accomplish this.

When the stream is **ordered** and **sequential**, which is the case of `Arrays.stream(elements).boxed()`, the `collect()` method does not use the combiner operator (*this is truth for java8 and java9 current realease, and however is not guaranteed to work exactly the same in next releases, because many optimizations can occur*).

This implementation keeps the order of the stream, and as mentioned before works fine in the current releases. Like the answer in the link below says, and also in my personal opinion, i find very difficult that the implementation of `collect` in sequential streams will ever need to use the combiner.

The code of the collect method is the following:

```
public static int[] deleteNth(int[] elements, int maxOcurrs) {
    return Arrays.stream(elements).boxed()
            .collect(() -> new ArrayList<Integer>(),
                    (list, elem) -> {
                        if (Collections.frequency(list, elem) < maxOcurrs) list.add(elem);
                    },
                    (list1, list2) -> { 
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Undefined combiner"); 
                    })
            .stream()
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
            .toArray();
}
```

This `collector` creates an `ArrayList`, and when is goind to add the new element checks if the `maxOcurrences` is met, if is not, then adds the element. Like mentioned before, and in the answer below, the combiner is not called at all. This persforms a little better than `n^2`.

More information of why the combiner method is not called in sequentials streams can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210176/can-a-collectors-combiner-function-ever-be-used-on-sequential-streams).

Comment: So basically you're checking if list has less than N elements and adding them when true, right? Can you explain why my approach wasn't working?

Comment: Your approach wasn't working because you were checking against all the elements not just the ones you have until that point. E.g. with `{2,2,2,2}` if you check against the hole list you get 4 repetitions, and in the filter you discard them all. If you instead start with `{}`, then add `2`, first check reps is `0<n` -> `{2}`, then add another `2`, check reps is `1<n` -> `{2,2}`, and finally want to add another `2`, first check reps `2<n` here `n=2` so you don't add more elements, and end with the current `{2,2}` list.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I've found to accomplish the task at hand is as follows:

```
public static int[] deleteNth(int[] elements, int maxOccurrences) {
    return Arrays.stream(elements)
                 .boxed()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                        LinkedHashMap::new,
                        Collectors.counting()))
                 .entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .flatMapToInt(entry ->
                    IntStream.generate(entry::getKey)
                             .limit(Math.min(maxOccurrences, entry.getValue())))
                 .toArray();
}
```

We first group the elements and then apply a `Collectors.counting()` as a downstream collector to get us the counts of a given element. After that is done we simply map a given number `n` number of times and then collect to an array with the `toArray` eager operations.

Comment: This does not guarantees the order, which **may** be required.

Comment: @JoseDaSilva there you have it.

Comment: No i mean the order of the elements e.g. `n=2` and `{2,3,2,2,2}`, here the output would be `{2, 2, 3}`. But should be `{2, 3, 2}` ?, we don't know yet.

Comment: I'm gonna save that neat collect trick, thanks for your solution

Answer (score 2):

Actually you exclude elements that are superior to the `maxOcurrences` value :

```
.filter(x -> Collections.frequency(ints, x) <= maxOcurrences)
```

I am not sure that a full `Stream` solution be the best choice for this use case as you want to add some values according to how many was "currently collected" for these values.

Here it how I would implement that :

```
public class DeleteN {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(deleteNth(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1 }, 1)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(deleteNth(new int[] { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, 2)));
    }

    public static int[] deleteNth(int[] elements, int maxOcurrences) {

        Map<Integer, Long> actualOccurencesByNumber = new HashMap<>();
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.stream(elements)
              .forEach(i -> {
                  Long actualValue = actualOccurencesByNumber.computeIfAbsent(i, k -> Long.valueOf(0L));
                  if (actualValue < maxOcurrences) {
                      result.add(i);
                      actualOccurencesByNumber.computeIfPresent(i, (k, v) -> v + 1L);
                  }
              });

        return result.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
    }
}
```

Output :

> [1, 2, 3, 4]
>
> [2, 2]