# Recursive use of Stream.flatMap()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Consider the following class:

```
public class Order {

    private String id;

    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.id;
    }

    // getters & setters
}
```

NOTE: *It is important to note that I **cannot modify** this class*, because I'm consuming it from an external API.

Also consider the following hierarchy of orders:

```
Order o1 = new Order();
o1.setId("1");
Order o11 = new Order();
o11.setId("1.1");
Order o111 = new Order();
o111.setId("1.1.1");
List<Order> o11Children = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(o111));
o11.setOrders(o11Children);

Order o12 = new Order();
o12.setId("1.2");
List<Order> o1Children = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(o11, o12));
o1.setOrders(o1Children);

Order o2 = new Order();
o2.setId("2");
Order o21 = new Order();
o21.setId("2.1");
Order o22 = new Order();
o22.setId("2.2");
Order o23 = new Order();
o23.setId("2.3");
List<Order> o2Children = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(o21, o22, o23));
o2.setOrders(o2Children);

List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(o1, o2));
```

Which could be visually represented this way:

```
1
1.1
1.1.1
1.2
2
2.1
2.2
2.3
```

Now, I want to flatten this hierarchy of orders into a `List`, so that I get the following:

```
[1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.2, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3]
```

I've managed to do it by recursively using `flatMap()` (along with a helper class), as follows:

```
List<Order> flattened = orders.stream()
    .flatMap(Helper::flatten)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is the helper class:

```
public final class Helper {

    private Helper() {
    }

    public static Stream<Order> flatten(Order order) {
        return Stream.concat(
            Stream.of(order), 
            order.getOrders().stream().flatMap(Helper::flatten)); // recursion here
    }
}
```

The following line:

```
System.out.println(flattened);
```

Produces the following output:

```
[1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.2, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3]
```

So far so good. The result is absolutely correct.

However, [**after reading this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229373/why-filter-after-flatmap-is-not-completely-lazy-in-java-streams), I had some concerns regarding the usage of `flatMap()` within a recursive method. Particularly, I wanted to know how the stream was being expanded (if that's the term). So I modified the `Helper` class and used `peek(System.out::println)` to check this:

```
public static final class Helper {

    private Helper() {
    }

    public static Stream<Order> flatten(Order order) {
        return Stream.concat(
            Stream.of(order), 
            order.getOrders().stream().flatMap(Helper::flatten))
        .peek(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

And the output was:

```
1
1.1
1.1
1.1.1
1.1.1
1.1.1
1.2
1.2
2
2.1
2.1
2.2
2.2
2.3
2.3
```

I'm not sure if this is the output that should be printed.

So, I wonder if it's OK to let intermediate streams contain repeated elements. Furthermore, what are the pros and cons of this approach? Is it correct, after all, to use `flatMap()` this way? Is there a better way to achieve the same?

Comment: Just curious: why do you set the id after creating the order rather than making it an argument to the constructor?

Comment: @sprinter I cannot modify the `Order` class since it's parte of an API i'm consuming.

Comment: Ah I see. Then most of my answer is pretty useless. It might be worth adding that piece of information to your question.

Comment: @sprinter I'll edit it, thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, I used the same pattern with a generic `Tree` class and didn’t have a wrong feeling with it. The only difference is, that the `Tree` class itself offered a `children()` and `allDescendants()` methods, both returning a `Stream` and the latter building on the former. This is related to [“Should I return a Collection or a Stream?”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24676877/2711488) and [“Naming java methods that return streams”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28805077/2711488).

From a `Stream`s perspective, there is no difference between a `flatMap` to children of a different type (i.e. when traversing a property) and a `flatMap` to children of the same type. There is also no problem if the returned stream contains the same element again, as there is no relationship between the elements of the streams. In principle, you can use `flatMap` as a `filter` operation, using the pattern `flatMap(x -> condition? Stream.of(x): Stream.empty())`. It’s also possible to use it to duplicate elements like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32520472/2711488).

Comment: My concerns come from here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229373/why-filter-after-flatmap-is-not-completely-lazy-in-java-streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229373/why-filter-after-flatmap-is-not-completely-lazy-in-java-streams) It took me some time to find the question

Comment: This is a weakness in the implementation (lots of people consider it a bug), but it doesn’t invalidate your solution. Your approach is not wrong. And related performance issues regarding short-circuiting operations should be fixed by the JRE maintainers.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I wanted to know.

Comment: anything can be done to make the stream lazy? see this question too - http://stackoverflow.com/q/32749148

Comment: @bayou.io: yeah, I decided to make a general solution (aka workaround) for this, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32767282/2711488

Answer (score 22):

There is really no problem with you using `flatMap` in this way. Each of the intermediate steps in a stream are quite independent (by design) so there's no risk in your recursion. The main thing you need to watch out for is anything that might alter the underlying list while you are streaming it. In your case that does not seem to be a risk.

Ideally you would make this recursion part of the `Order` class itself:

```
class Order {
    private final List<Order> subOrders = new ArrayList<>();

    public Stream<Order> streamOrders() {
        return Stream.concat(
            Stream.of(this), 
            subOrders.stream().flatMap(Order::streamOrders));
    }
}
```

Then you can use `orders.stream().flatMap(Order::streamOrders)` which seems a bit more natural to me than using a helper class.

As a matter of interest, I tend to use these types of `stream` methods for allowing use of collection fields rather than a getter for the field. If the user of the method does not need to know anything about the underlying collection or need to be able to change it then returning a stream is convenient and safe.

I will note that there is one risk in your data structure you should be aware of: an order could be part of several other orders and can even be part of itself. This means that it's pretty trivial to cause infinite recursion and a stack overflow:

```
Order o1 = new Order();
o1.setOrders(Arrays.asList(o1));
o1.streamOrders();
```

There are lots of good patterns available to avoid these sorts of issues so please ask if you want some help in that area.

You point out that you can't alter the `Order` class. In that case I suggest you extend it to create your own safer version:

```
class SafeOrder extends Order {
    public SafeOrder(String id) {
        setId(id);
    }

    public void addOrder(SafeOrder subOrder) {
        getOrders().add(subOrder);
    }

    public Stream<SafeOrder> streamOrders() {
        return Stream.concat(Stream.of(this), subOrders().flatMap(SafeOrder::streamOrders));
    }

    private Stream<SafeOrder> subOrders() {
        return getOrders().stream().map(o -> (SafeOrder)o);
    }
}
```

This is a fairly safe cast because you expect users to use `addOrder`. Not foolproof as they could still call `getOrders` and add an `Order` rather than a `SafeOrder`. Again there are patterns to prevent that if you are interested.

Comment: My concerns come from here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229373/why-filter-after-flatmap-is-not-completely-lazy-in-java-streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229373/why-filter-after-flatmap-is-not-completely-lazy-in-java-streams) It took me some time to find the question

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner that issue doesn't effect the correctness of this solution at all. It is about the conditions under which a stream can be short circuited - the OP in that case is showing that under some conditions the stream operation should terminate but doesn't. The answer is still correct it's just that sometimes the JRE does more processing than it needs to.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to check the correctness of my approach regarding the linked question, but your answer regarding how to correctly design on this scenario is also very useful.