# Java Stream collect all children

Tags: java-8, java-stream, hierarchical-data, children, collectors

I would like to write a Java 8 `stream().collect` function that return a `List<T>` containing all children and subchildren of a node within a hierarchical structure. For example `TreeItem<T>` `getChildren()` and all of the children's children and so on, reducing it to a single list.

---

By the way, here is my final solution as generic method. Very effective and very useful.

```
public static <T> Stream<T> treeStream(T root, boolean includeRoot, Function<T, Stream<? extends T>> nextChildren)
{
    Stream<T> stream = nextChildren.apply(root).flatMap(child -> treeStream(child, true, nextChildren));
    return includeRoot ? Stream.concat(Stream.ofNullable(root), stream) : stream;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `TreeItem` class please (or, at least, its relevant methods)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32656888/2711488

Comment: @Mureinik "My" TreeItem class is javafx.scene.control.TreeItem. Relevant method is getChildren().

Answer (score 0):

You have to flatten the tree using a recursive function. You have an example here: http://squirrel.pl/blog/2015/03/04/walking-recursive-data-structures-using-java-8-streams/

Comment: That's okay, but recursion is generally a bad idea since the stack could potentially become overflowed.

Comment: If the tree is very deep, you can use [trampolines](https://github.com/aol/cyclops/wiki/trampoline-:-stackless-recursion-for-java-8) — here is a good [article in french](https://www.infoq.com/fr/articles/trampoline-java8) to avoid stack overflows: the code becomes less readable though.

Comment: Trampolines... I didn't know them, interesting.

Answer (score 0):

In order not to fall with stack overflow there is a way to replace stack with queue in heap.

This solution creates stream from iterator that lazily navigates tree holding next items in [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html).

Depending on type of queue traversal can be [depth first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [breadth first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

```
class TreeItem {
    Collection<TreeItem> children = new ArrayList<>();
}

Stream<TreeItem> flatten(TreeItem root) {
    Iterator<TreeItem> iterator = new Iterator<TreeItem>() {
        Queue<TreeItem> queue = new LinkedList<>(Collections.singleton(root)); //breadth first
//      Queue<TreeItem> queue = Collections.asLifoQueue(new LinkedList<>(Collections.singleton(root))); //depth first

        @Override public boolean hasNext() {
            return !queue.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override public TreeItem next() {
            TreeItem next = queue.poll();
            queue.addAll(next.children);
            return next;
        }
    };
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0), false);
}
```