# (Java) Flatten JSONArray of JSONObject to [[]] with Java8

Tags: java, arrays, json, java-8

Im using net.sf.json.JSONArray and net.sf.json.JSONObject.
JSONArray contains multiple JSONObject.

Basically this:

```
[
    {
        "obj1": [
            {
                "ID": 12
                "NAME":"Whatever",
                "XY":[1,2]
            },
            {
                "ID": 34
                "NAME":"Again",
                "XY":[23,43]
            },
            etc
        ]
    },
    { "obj2": repeat}
]
```

I would like to flatten that with Java 8, i.e. result:

```
[
    {
        "obj1": [
                    [12,'Whatever',1,2],
                    [34,'Again',23,43],
                    etc...
        ]
    },
    { "obj2": repeat}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite you can easily accomplish this in imperative manner with/out recursion, it might be easier to implement in functional style. I'm not sure if I'm good at idiomatic functional code in Java 8, but you'd need:

- A collector to collect items to a single array

```java
static Collector<Object, JSONArray, JSONArray> toJSONArray() {
    return Collector.of(
            JSONArray::new,     // Create a new array
            JSONArray::add,     // Add each element to the target array
            (a1, a2) -> {       // Merge the second array into the first one
                a1.addAll(a2);
                return a1;
            },
            identity()          // Return the populated array itself
    );
}
```

- A recursive flatten method (inspired by [Recursive use of Stream.flatMap()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656888/recursive-use-of-stream-flatmap)). Not sure whether it can be implemented easier (`Q43481457` is just the current class name).

```java
static Stream<?> flatten(final Object value) {
    return value instanceof Collection
            ? ((Collection<?>) value).stream().flatMap(Q43481457::flatten) // Flatten recursively
            : Stream.of(value);                                            // Otherwise wrap a single element into a stream
}
```

- And the main code:

```java
@SupressWarnings("unchecked")
final Collection<JSON> jsonArray = (Collection<JSON>) originalJsonArray;
final JSONArray flatJSONArray = jsonArray.stream()
        .map(json -> (Map<?, ?>) json)          // All outer array elements are JSON objects and maps in particular
        .map(jsonObject -> jsonObject.values()  // Recursively flatten the JSON object values
                .stream()
                .flatMap(Q43481457::flatten)
                .collect(toJSONArray())         // ... collecting them to JSON arrays
        )
        .collect(toJSONArray());                // ... which are collected to JSON arrays
System.out.println(flatJSONArray);
```

Output:

> [[12,"Whatever",1,2],[34,"Again",23,43]]

Comment: To me it doesnt compile. At .values() here :
`.map(jsonObject -> jsonObject.values()`

cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method values()

Comment: @sherkal What do you use to compile with?

Comment: NetBeans 8 JDK 8

Comment: @sherkal Strange. I'm using `javac` from JDK 1.8/121 - works fine.

Comment: @sherkal What are your imports?

Comment: import java.util.Collection;  
import java.util.Map;  
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;  
import java.util.stream.Collector;  
import java.util.stream.Stream;  
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;

Comment: @sherkal It's weird. What if you try to replace cast `(Map<?, ?>)` with `JSONObject` (or something like this, can't really recall)?

Comment: @sherkal It's really strange. What if you replace the lambda expression you mentioned in your comment with a anonymous class (not sure if NetBeans can do such a refactor) `Function<JSONObject, JSONArray>` (if I'm not mistaken)?

Comment: doesnt seem to work either :/ jsonObject is just an instance of Object it seems, tried casting it to JSONObject but doesnt work.

Comment: @sherkal Here are my imports: `import java.util.Collection`; `import java.util.Map`; `import java.util.stream.Collector`; `import java.util.stream.Stream`; `import net.sf.json.JSON`; `import net.sf.json.JSONArray`; `import static java.util.function.Function.identity`; `import static net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject`; . How is your `jsonArray` typed? It must be at least `Collection<JSON>` to be able to provide a stream of `JSON` instances.

Comment: just JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

Comment: @sherkal This is probably the issue: `JSONArray` is a raw list. Cast it to `Collection<JSON>` so your stream could be typed.

Answer (score 0):

### Usage

```
JSONArray array = ...;
JSONArray flattedArray = flatten(array);

JSONObject map = ...;
JSONObject flattedMap = flatten(map);
```

### Implementation

When the json structure changed the implementation has undergone tremendous changes that you can comparing my commit history on [github](https://github.com/holi-java/api-test/commit/50727b7ac23ec7abf744e957a15f7fad67c1995a?diff=split). and the [tests](https://github.com/holi-java/api-test/blob/50727b7ac23ec7abf744e957a15f7fad67c1995a/src/test/java/test/java/streams/JSONObjectFlattenTest.java#L55-L126) can tell you how I implementing your features.

```
public JSONArray flatten(Collection<?> array) {
    return array.stream().flatMap(this::flatting).collect(toJSONArray());
}

private Stream<?> flatting(Object it) {
    if (it instanceof Collection) {
        return ((Collection<?>) it).stream();
    }
    if (it instanceof Map) {
        return Stream.of(flatten((Map<?, ?>) it));
    }
    return Stream.of(it);
}

public JSONObject flatten(Map<?, ?> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream().collect(
            JSONObject::new,
            (it, field) -> it.put(field.getKey(), flatten(field.getValue())),
            JSONObject::putAll
    );
}

private Object flatten(Object it) {
    if (it instanceof Collection) {
        return ((Collection<?>) it).stream().map(this::flatten)
                                            .collect(toJSONArray());
    }
    if (it instanceof Map) {
        return flatten(((Map<?, ?>) it).values());
    }
    return it;
}

private <T> Collector<T, ?, JSONArray> toJSONArray() {
    return toCollection(JSONArray::new);
}
```

Comment: this gives me instead one big array :

[12,"Whatever",1,2,34,"Again",23,43]

Comment: @sherkal are you sure? the result is what your expected in my test.

Comment: @sherkal the test I have checked in [github](https://github.com/holi-java/api-test/blob/8c95f2b91271050508dc86fb66f33d073466061c/src/test/java/test/java/streams/JSONObjectFlattenTest.java#L23-L49) and you can see.

Comment: my bad... my structure is a bit different after all. I'll update my question. Sorry :s

Comment: @sherkal have you updated your question? I can't see that it is updated.

Comment: kinda, Im using the answer above. Deeper on each JSONArray