# Why the BufferedReader::lines() creates a Stream<T> through Iterator<T> instead of Spliterator<T>?

Tags: lambda, io, java-8, java-stream

I was surprised to see that [`BufferedReader` `lines()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/io/BufferedReader.java) method creates an instance of `Stream<T>` with an implementation of  the `Iterator<T>` interface, instead of `Spliterator<T>`. For many reasons there are several advantages for using a `Spliterator<T>`,  even without parallelism. For instance, [Brian Goetz states in its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31212695/1140754) to the question [Iterator versus Stream of Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31210791/1140754):

> `Spliterator` has fundamentally lower per-element access costs than `Iterator`, even sequentially.

So, why the `BufferedReader::lines()` creates a `Stream<T>` through `Iterator<T>` instead of `Spliterator<T>`?

Comment: People use what the are familiar with. There is no reason why JRE developers should be different.

Comment: IMHO a JRE developer that is developing a new feature closely related with new JDK8 API and specifically the `Stream<T>` should be aware of it.

Comment: That’s what’s going through my mind as well, especially, when it comes to the new Java 9 methods as nowadays, the advantages of the `Spliterator` should become widely known. Still, I try my best not to judge too fast. We don’t know about the workload the particular developer had to handle the day (s)he implemented such a method…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no technical reason to implement it using an `Iterator`. The statement from Brian Goetz still holds. Why I doubt that you will notice a performance difference in this specific case, the `Spliterator` based implementation would be much simpler, as all it needs is a `tryAdvance` method implementation which invokes `readLine()`, in contrast to the iterator implementation which has to maintain state to remember whether `hasNext()` has been called already and with which result.

So the actual reason is the same reason, why lots of developers here do it. Iterators are familiar, therefore developers quickly go and implement it, knowing that they can wrap it (in my earlier answers I did it as well). In case of the JRE development, there might be a historical reason, e.g. that it was implemented before the `Spliterator` was introduced and only refactored afterwards.

Note that there are worse offenders, like `String.chars()`, which could be implemented as a fast, lightweight, array based spliterator with perfect parallel support. Instead, you’ll get a `PrimitiveIterator.OfInt` based implementation in Java 8 which is more complicated, does waste performance and intrinsically has poor parallel support (the underlying implementation has to *buffer* the data).

Thankfully, `String.chars()` will be fixed in Java 9, which does not imply that every involved developer got the message. I just looked at `Matcher.results()`,  introduced in Java 9, and it also uses the `Iterator` detour (in contrast to `Scanner.findAll`, to name a positive counter-example). Of course, this all might change before release.

But unnecessary `Iterator` detours in Stream producing methods are unlikely to disappear soon. In some cases, it’s not even worth wasting time to rewrite the methods, once they are implemented the way they are…