# Java 8 Chaining Operations

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream, chain

I have some java code that I want to chain together using Java 8's stream. Here's the code in the current state:

```
public class FooOperations {
    public List<FooB> getFooB() {
        List<FooA> fooAs = fooAOperation.getFooA();
        List<FooB> fooBs = fooBOperation.getFooB(fooAs);
        return fooBs;
    }
}

public class FooAOperation {
    public List<FooA> getFooA() {
        return foos.parallelStream().map(build()).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

public class FooBOperation {
    public List<FooB> getFooB(List<FooA> fooAs) {
        return fooAs.parallelStream()
                    .map(fooA -> generateFooB(fooA))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

But I want to chain these operations into one line in the `FooOperations` class. Something like this:

```
return fooAOperation.getFooA().map(fooA -> FooBOperation::getFooB(fooA)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which would require the `FooAOperation` class to return a stream rather than a list.

My objective is to chain these two processes together so that the `FooBOperation` doesn't have to wait for the full list of `FooA` objects to be populated before it can start processing; I want to make it so that it can start processing the objects individually as soon as they're ready. Kind of a like a message queue.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: You have already answered the question yourself.

Comment: Refer also to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676877/should-i-return-a-collection-or-a-stream