# Convert List<List<String>> to Stream<Stream<String>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Requirement:
Please consider a function which generates `List<List<String>>` and return the same.

So in Java 1.7, this can be considered as:

```
public List<List<String> function(){
  List<List<String>> outList = new ArrayList<>();
  List<String> inList = new ArrayList<>();
  inList.add("ABC");
  inList.add("DEF");
  outList.add(inList);
  outList.add(inList);
  return outList;
}
```

Now in Java 8, the signature of the function provided to me is:

```
public Stream<Stream<String>> function() {
      List<List<String>> outList = new ArrayList<>();
      List<String> inList = new ArrayList<>();
      inList.add("ABC");
      inList.add("DEF");
      outList.add(inList);
      outList.add(inList);
      //How to convert the outList into Stream<Stream<String>> and return.
}
```

How to convert `List<List<String>>` into `Stream<Stream<String>>`.

Comment: Answer by @YCF_L will do the work, but I have another question: why do you want to return `Stream<Stream<String>>` if you're asked to - *Please consider a function which generates List<List<String>> and return the same.* ?

Comment: The function signature provided to me are like
`public Stream<Stream<String>> function() {
return Stream.of()
}`
But as of now, since I am not comfortable in Streams, I have worked it out with List<List<String>>

Comment: Returning a `Stream` is a *bad idea*. You have no idea what the state of the stream is. The caller doesn't even know if they can iterate the stream at all. If you pass Streams around, everyone can break anyone elses code just by using the Stream!

Comment: @Polygnome I think it is not that bad in some situations, instead, it can be the right choice, read this, [Should I return a Collection or a Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676877/should-i-return-a-collection-or-a-stream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to convert `List<List<String>>` into `Stream<Stream<String>>`:

You need just to this :

```
return outList.stream()
        .map(List::stream);
```

---

Or another way without using Lists, you can use :

```
public Stream<Stream<String>> function() {
    Stream<String> inList = Stream.of("ABC", "DEF");
    return Stream.of(inList, inList);
}
```

Comment: That have worked. But for learning, what is the return statement is like `return Stream.of`
How to make that into Stream<Stream<String>>